# StoryBoards and UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm new to storyboarding and I'm just wondering is it possible to link one UITabBarController to another?  How would I go about replacing the Tabs of the 1st TabBarViewController with the 2nd TabBarViewControllers tabs when opening the 2nd TabBarViewController?

[image: My StoryBoard I have linked the mainTabbarViewController using Relationship seque - ViewController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is have sets of view controllers. So you want to "switch" tab view controllers, you essentially remove all the current ones, then provide another set. You cannot embed one inside the other.

If you really really want to, you could set up some method in your appDelegate to actually swap out one tab controller for another, but that's overkill.

I did something like this in a shipping app - I had a login view that became the rootViewController of the app until the user logged in. Then I transitioned to a tab controller (fade in and out) - looked nice.